# Webserver Node Raspberry

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose, router

I'm trying to build a Rest api on a raspberry Pi with Node.js, Express, MongoDB and Mongoose according to this tutorial :
https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

I have 2 questions :
- I'd like to access my server from everywhere (not just locally).
Which port or process should I execute ?

- Is it possible to make it for a raspberry Pi or not ?
  (I want it to be an api and a mongoDB stockage space as well)

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: It is possible to run it as long as you have enough memory ! Running your Node Server and MongoDB server on the same PI would be possible but as @Karthic stated it, the processing would be really limited ! Amazon EC2 free tier might be something suitable for your case !

Answer (score 1):

First, The port express JS will be already set as 8080. To run your Express JS server you have to do the `npm start` I am not sure how to do in in a Pi. If you do get it working on a pi you can make it as an api by connecting the pi to the internet and running it online forever.I dont not recommend you run your api on a pi because the processing is limited, it would be better if you can you run it using Amazon EC2.